# Ruby - remove columns from csv file and convert to pipe delimited txt file

Tags: ruby, csv, file-io

I'm trying to take a CSV file, strip a few columns, and then output a pipe delimited text file.

Here's my code, which almost works. The only problem is the `CSV.generate` block is adding double quotes around the whole thing, as well as a random comma with double quotes around it where the line break is.

```
require 'csv'

original = CSV.read('original.csv', { headers: true, return_headers: true })

original.delete('Column header 1')
original.delete('Column header 2')
original.delete('Column header 3')

csv_string = CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << original
end

pipe_string = csv_string.tr(",","|")

File.open('output.txt', 'w+') do |f|
  f.write(pipe_string)
end
```

Is there a better way to do this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
require 'csv'

original = CSV.read('original.csv', { headers: true, return_headers: true })

original.delete('Column header 1')
original.delete('Column header 2')
original.delete('Column header 3')

CSV.open('output.txt', 'w', col_sep: '|') do |csv|
  original.each do |row|
    csv << row
  end
end
```

Comment: col_sep...just what I needed to know. Thanks!